# Swift parsing data from POST request

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

This should be pretty simple but it's doing my head in. I'm doing a post request with swift and I get some Json data back:

```
Optional({
authString = "bWF0dEB0YXN0";
data =     {
    x = asd;
    y = 1234;
};
success = 1;
})
```

I can successfully get `authString` and `success` but I can't seem to be able to parse `data`

this works:

```
let auth = parseJSON["authString"] as? String
```

This doesn't:

```
let dataArray = parseJSON["data"] as? NSDictionary
println(dataArray["x"])
```

This returns nil:

```
let dataArray = parseJSON["data"] as? Array<NSDictionary>
println(dataArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let dataArray = parseJSON["data"] as? NSDictionary
println(dataArray?["x"])
//               ^ HERE
```

Because `dataArray` is `Optional<NSDictionary>`, you have to use ["Optional Chaining"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) syntax.